# Как автоматизировать открытие отрытие окон в терминале

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

Народ, думаю над такой проблемой. Может кто подскажет как решить. Мне на текущем проекте нужно открывать очень много вкладок в терминале:

- 2 вкладки чтобы по рабочим директориям ходить и искать куски кода в файлах;
- 3 вкладки с различными логами, которые я смотрю через tail;
- 2 вкладки с демонами, которые при обновлении файлов пересобирают проект и рестартуют апач.

Для работы с териналами я использую terminator Кто знает, как бы мне можно было автоматизировать процесс открытия этих окон? Возможно ли написать какой-то скрипт, который будет открывать эти окна.

```
Вкладка 1
- открытие окна
- подключение к ssh
- ввод пароля
- переход в указанную категорию
- выполнение команды tail -f -n warn.log

Вкладка 2
- открытие окна
- подключение к ssh
- ввод пароля
- переход в указанную категорию
- выполнение команды node watch.js
```

и т.д.

Comment: [tmux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16752088/4279) или [emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2703743/4279) ([winner](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/2710) или без) позволяют сессии достаточно прямолинейно скриптовать

Comment: Вот похожий вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188959/open-a-new-tab-in-gnome-terminal-using-command-line. Правда он конкретно о gnome-terminal, но ответ достаточно универсальный.